# Mongoose aggregate Lookup - How to filter by specific id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to make a aggregate pipeline - `$lookup` to receive from another
collection only items that are not equal to specific _id

for example :

ClinicsCollection :

```
{_id:1,name:'some name1'}
{_id:2,name:'some name2'}
{_id:3,name:'some name3'}
```

BusinessCollection :

```
{_id:1,name:"some business name",clinics:[1,2,3]}
```

My aggregate pipeline query :

```
db.business.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(businessId)}},
    {$lookup: 
    {from: "ClinicsCollection", localField: "clinics", foreignField: "_id", as: "clinics"}},

]
```

I want to filter all clinics that are not equal to specific id number let say _id : 1

expected result :

```
 clinics :[
    {_id:2,name:'some name2'}
    {_id:3,name:'some name3'}
 ]
```

How can i achieve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aUpHqL8hS-Y) with mongodb **3.6** and above

You need to just use `$match` with the child collection as you do with the parent collection in the first stage.

```
db.BusinessCollection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "clinics": { "$type": "array" }}},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "ClinicsCollection",
    "let": { "clinics": "$clinics" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [
            { "$in": ["$_id", "$$clinics"] },
            { "$not": { "$eq": ["$_id", 1] }}
          ]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "clinics"
  }}
])
```

Comment: err : MongoError : $in requires an array as a second argument, found : missing

Comment: oh in my db it was clinicsIds under business .. sorry
how can i get only specific fields from the lookup ?
Thanks

Comment: why do you need a let here?

Answer (score 2):

You can try below aggregation for mongodb version below 3.6

```
db.business.aggregate([
    {$match : {_id : 1}},
    {$lookup : {from : "clinics", localField : "clinics", foreignField : "_id", as : "clinics"}},
    {$addFields : {clinics : {$filter : {input : "$clinics", as : "c", cond : {$ne : ["$$c._id", 1]}}}}}
]).pretty()
```

result

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "some business name", "clinics" : [ { "_id" : 2, "name" : "some name2" }, { "_id" : 3, "name" : "some name3" } ] }
```