# How to count post comment in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new in Nodejs and Mongosee, this easy in Php and Mysql with many solution but do not know how query in Mongosee and Nodejs
Here is my code 
Post Schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String
});
const postModel = mongoose.model('post', postSchema);
export default postModel;
```

Comment Schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  postId: {
    ref: 'post',
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
  },
  title: String,
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
const commentModel = mongoose.model('comment', commentSchema);
export default commentModel;
```

How to query result like

```
{
"_id": "5e7c7217068570095363ecb0",
"title": "Test Post ",
"description": "My description",
"__v": 0,
"comment_count": 10,
},
{
"_id": "5e7c7218068570095363ecb1",
"title": "Test Post ",
"description": "My description",
"__v": 0,
"comment_count": 0,
}
```

Comment: You need to perform [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html) with [$lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215731/mongoose-aggregate-lookup-how-to-filter-by-specific-id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
const posts = await Post.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      let: { postId: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$postId", "$postId"] } } }],
      as: "comment_count"
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { comment_count: { $size: "$comment_count" }}}
]);
```

Comment: Déjà vu! I've posted comment with your answer :)

Comment: @Valijon oops I didn't see. :-)

Comment: @Ashh, Oh thanks you also i am edit to { $lookup: { from: 'comments', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'postId', as: 'comment_count' } }, { $addFields: { comment_count: { $size: '$comment_count' } } } and working